# php como eliminar un div con expresiones regulares

Tags: php, regex

tengo un bloque de código de dailymotion pero necesito borrar un div y dejar el resto del código, usando expresiones regulares con php

```
<div class="media_embed">
<div height="" style="position:relative;padding-bottom:56.25%;height:0;overflow:hidden;" width=""><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="100%" src="url del video" style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;overflow:hidden" type="text/html" width="100%"></iframe></div>
</div>
```

y dejarlo asi:

```
<div height="" style="position:relative;padding-bottom:56.25%;height:0;overflow:hidden;" width=""><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="100%" src="url del video" style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;overflow:hidden" type="text/html" width="100%"></iframe></div>
```

sin el div de `<div class="media_embed"></div>`

me podrian ayudar porfavor
Gracias

Comment: No es posible parsear HTML con expresiones regulares.

Comment: Tampoco soy partidario de las expresiones regulares para manipular HTML, para eso existe [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php). Aparte, como idea simple, podría ser suficiente con eliminar `class="media_embed"`, a menos que el _div_ represente un problema por sí mismo.

Comment: gracias pero estoy usando AMP y no me deja manipular el HTML con el phpDOM es por eso que busco una expresión regular para hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

En general, no es recomendable usar expresiones regulares para modificar código HTML, pueden surgir variantes que impidan que se ejecute correctamente, sin embargo. Si tu caso va a ser siempre igual.

- `<div class="media_embed">` sin más atributos
- `<div>` seguido de `<iframe>`
- `</iframe></div>` seguido de salto de línea
- `</div>` como cierre del div inicial

```
$original = <<<STR
<div class="media_embed">
<div height="" style="position:relative;padding-bottom:56.25%;height:0;overflow:hidden;" width=""><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="100%" src="url del video" style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;overflow:hidden" type="text/html" width="100%"></iframe></div>
</div>
STR;

$replaced = preg_replace("/\<div class=\"media_embed\"\>(.*?)\n\<\/div\>/is", '$1', $original);
echo htmlentities($replaced);
```

Resultado:

```
<div height="" style="position:relative;padding-bottom:56.25%;height:0;overflow:hidden;" width=""><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="100%" src="url del video" style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;overflow:hidden" type="text/html" width="100%"></iframe></div>
```

[Explicación de la expresión (en inglés)](https://regexr.com/5drpc)

Puedes hacerlo simplemente con [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php) para obtener el mismo resultado:

```
$replaced = str_replace(['<div class="media_embed">', '</iframe></div>'],
    ['', '</iframe>'],
    $original);
```

Al usar arreglos con `str_replace()`:

- El primer elemento de búsqueda `<div class="media_embed">` se remplaza con el primer elemento de remplazo, cadena vacía
- Al segundo elemento de búsqueda `</iframe></div>` se elimina el cierre de *div*

Answer (score -1):

Puedes ocultar la capa contenedora "media_embed" mediante jquery:

`$('.media_embed').contents().unwrap();`

```js
$('.media_embed').contents().unwrap();
```

```css
.media_embed {background-color:#000000;height:50px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="media_embed">
<div>Capa con contenido que quieres mostrar</div>
</div>
```

Encontré esta solución en https://stackoverflow.com/a/11252946/2496770

Comment: ¿Y cómo sería en PHP? Porque la pregunta especifica que se pretende hacer en PHP, no Javascript.

Comment: gracias amigo, si funciona pero busco hacerlo con php ya que estoy usando AMP y tengo que modificar el html antes de que se rendere